# Non-strict sequences with redux-observable and RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

My app has a modal with a spinner that's displayed whenever a long blocking action is taking place.
There's several of these long blocking actions, each with an action that marks its start and finish.

Given the "stream of actions", whenever one of the start action is dispatched, I want to dispatch the `showWaitingIndication` action until the corresponding end action is dispatched and then dispatch `hideWaitingIndication`. If another start action is dispatched and then it's corresponding end action is dispatched while the first blocking action is in progress, it shouldn't call `showWaitingIndication` again or `hideWaitingIndication`. Nor should `hideWaitingIndication` be dispatched while an action is still active.

Basically the idea is that as long as a blocking action is active, the waiting indication shouldn't hide.

e.g.

`StartA` -> dispatch(`showWaitingIndication`) -> other events -> `endA` -> dispatch(`hideWaitingIndication`)

`StartA` -> dispatch(`showWaitingIndication`) -> `startB` -> `endB` (shouldn't call hide) -> `endA` -> dispatch(`hideWaitingIndication`)

Also
`StartA` -> dispatch(`showWaitingIndication`) -> `startB` -> `endA` (shouldn't call hide!) -> `endB` -> dispatch(`hideWaitingIndication`)

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to implement this with streams (which I strongly believe are a good fit for this issue).

So far I've come up with something like this (which doesn't work)

```
    let showHideActionPairs = getShowHideActionPairs(); // { "startA": "endA", "startB": "endB"}
    let showActions  = Object.keys(showHideActionPairs);

    return action$ => action$.pipe(
        filter(action => Object.keys(showHideActionPairs).includes(action.type)),
        switchMap(val =>
            {
                let hideAction = showHideActionPairs[val.type];
                return concat(
                    of(waitingIndicationShowAction),
                    empty().pipe(
                            ofType(hideAction),
                            mapTo(waitingIndicationHideAction)
                    ))
            }
        )
    );
```

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: 'If another start action is dispatched, it shouldn't call showWaitingIndication' - you mean while the current action is being processed and another one is dispatched it shouldn't emit `showWaitingIndication`, right?

Comment: @AndreiGătej exactly! Updated the question to clarify

Comment: And what should happen with the second action? Should it be processed as well or skipped?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Updated the question with relevant cases. Basically the idea is that as long as a blocking action is active, the waiting indication shouldn't hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem!

I think you could try this:

```js
const showHideActionPairs = getShowHideActionPairs(); // { "startA": "endA", "startB": "endB"}

actions$.pipe(
  windowWhen(() => actions$.pipe(filter(action => action.type === hideWaitingIndication))),
  
  mergeMap(
    window => window.pipe(
      mergeMap(
        action => someAsyncCall().pipe(
          mapTo(showHideActionPairs[action]),
          startWith(showHideActionPairs[action])
        )
      ),

      scan((acc, crtEndAction) => {
        // first time receiving this end action -> the beginning of the async call
        if (!(crtEndAction in acc)) {
          acc[crtEndAction] = true;

          return acc;
        }

        // if the `crtEndAction` exists, it means that the async call has finished
        const {[crtEndAction]: _, ...rest} = acc;

        return rest;
      }, Object.create(null)),

      filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).length === 0),

      mapTo(hideWaitingIndication),

      // a new window marks the beginning of the modal
      startWith(showWaitingIndication),
    )
  )
)
```

My first thought was that I need to a find a way to *represent* a **chain of events**, such that the chain starts at `showWaitingIndication` and ends with `hideWaitingIndication`. The end of the chain is actually indicated by the last completed async call(`end{N}`). So I considered it would be a good use case for `windowWhen`.

But what is a `window` ? A window is [nothing more than a `Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/windowWhen.ts#L130):

```js
/* ... */
const window = this.window = new Subject<T>();
this.destination.next(window);
/* ... */
```

The way `windowWhen(() => closeNotifier)` works is that it will send a `Subject`(a `window`) as a `next` value(that's why we have `mergeMap(window => ...)`) and it will push values(e.g actions) through it. We're accessing these values inside `window.pipe(...)`. When `closeNotifier` emits, the current `window` will `complete` and a new `window` will be created and passed along, so that subsequent actions will be sent through it. It's worth noting that a window is created by default [when the stream is subscribed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/windowWhen.ts#L77-L81):

```js
constructor(protected destination: Subscriber<Observable<T>>,
            private closingSelector: () => Observable<any>) {
  super(destination);
  this.openWindow(); // !
}
```

Let's say that a we're receiving the first action in the current window.

```js
mergeMap(
  action => someAsyncCall().pipe(
    mapTo(showHideActionPairs[action]),
    startWith(showHideActionPairs[action])
  )
),
```

As soon as the action is intercepted, we'll send its **expected end value**, so that it can be stored in the `scan`'s accumulator. When that async call of that action would be finished, it will send again that end value, so that it can be removed from the accumulator.
This way, we can determine the lifespan of a window, which will be closed when there are no more **end values** in the accumulator.

When this happens

```js
filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).length === 0),

mapTo(hideWaitingIndication),
```

we make sure that we notify that all the actions have finished their task.

Comment: Thank you! That's a very creative solution! The only issue here is `someAsyncCall()` - this call isn't being initiated by the waitingIndicator, but rather is called by different logic pieces of the app. The waitingIndicator can only know about the blocking action by looking at `startA` actions in the stream

Comment: @OpherV Hmm, then there must be a way to be notified when an action has finished its task. Could you elaborate on that? So I think `someAsyncCall` should be replaced with an observable that would emit when that action would've been finished.

Comment: got it to work as expected. Thank you so much! Also posted my own version, would love to hear your feedback if you have any.

Comment: @OpherV I'm glad you found the solution! It was my pleasure to help. Your version looks a lot more easier to understand and now I finally get what the _feature_ was about :D

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted Andrei's answer, as he was to one to point me out in the right direction, and his solution involving a `windowWhen` and `accumulator` was the right mind frame to tackle this issue. I'm also posting my own solution based on his for completeness' sake, as I feel the logic here is more explicit (and personally was easier for me to wrap my head around as I was searching for the solution):

```js
let showHideActionPairs = getShowHideActionPairs();
const relevantActionsTypesArray = Object.keys(showHideActionPairs).concat(Object.values(showHideActionPairs));

actions$ => actions$.pipe(
        // close the "window" when a hide action is received
        windowWhen(() => actions$.pipe(ofType(waitingIndicationHideActionName),)),

        mergeMap(
            window => window.pipe(
                // filter to only look at start/end actions
                ofType.apply(null, relevantActionsTypesArray),
                scan((accumulator, action) => {
                    let waitingForEndAction  = "startAction" in accumulator;
                    // first time we see a start action
                    if (!waitingForEndAction && action.type in showHideActionPairs) {
                        accumulator.startAction = action.type;
                        accumulator.actionable = true;
                    // found the right end action
                    } else if (waitingForEndAction && action.type === showHideActionPairs[accumulator.startAction]) {
                        accumulator.endAction = action.type;
                        accumulator.actionable = true;
                    // any other case is not actionable (will not translate to to an action)
                    }  else {
                        accumulator.actionable = false;
                    }
                    return accumulator;
                }, {}),
                // accumulator spits out stuff for every action but we only care about the actionables
                filter(obj => obj.actionable),
                map(obj => {
                    if (obj.endAction){
                        return waitingIndicationHideAction
                    } else if (obj.startAction) {
                        return waitingIndicationShowAction
                    }
                }),
            )
        )
    )

};
```